# std::thread and std::endl no expected output

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying out some examples from `C++11 threads` I see some surprising results. With the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello concurrent world " << std::endl;
}
void do_something() {
    std::cout << "[background_task] --> [ do_something ]" << std::endl;
}
void do_something_else() {
    std::cout << "[background_task] --> [ do_something_else ]" << std::endl;
}
class background_task {
public:
    void operator()() const     {       
        do_something();
        do_something_else();
    }
};

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    std::thread t(hello);
    background_task bt;
    std::thread fn_obj_th(bt);
    t.join();
    fn_obj_th.join();
}
```

output is as follows

```
Hello concurrent world [background_task] --> [ do_something ]

[background_task] --> [ do_something_else ]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If I replace
`std::cout << "Hello concurrent world " << std::endl;`
with
`std::cout << "Hello concurrent world \n";`

Result is

```
Hello concurrent world
[background_task] --> [ do_something ]
[background_task] --> [ do_something_else ]
```

Why in case with `std::endl` I am not getting expected output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
std::cout << "Hello concurrent world " << std::endl;
```

is two *separate* outputs. While `std::cout` is thread-safe, that doesn't mean that two separate invocations of it is guaranteed to be atomic. A single output is atomic, but not two.

If you want a particular expression to be guaranteed to be atomically output, then you need to add your own synchronization primitives on top of `std::cout`.

Comment: Are you saying that std::cout << "Hello concurrent world " is getting executed first and then thread switching happening and std::endl; is happening after that, could you please explain

Comment: @Avinash: Yes, that's what I'm saying (more or less). You should probably investigate the concept of "atomic operations" in threading before continuing to use threads in your program.

Comment: @Avinash Try it with something other than a whitespace character.